# MYSQL - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, validation

I found an error in my code when i try to insert my form in db...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 2

Form:

```
<div class="form">
  <form id="contactform" method="POST" action=""> 
    <p class="contact"><label for="name">Name</label></p> 
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" required="" tabindex="1" type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="" type="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="username">Create a username</label></p> 
        <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required="" tabindex="2" type="text" value="<?php echo $username;?>"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="password">Create a password</label></p> 
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Set password"> 

    <p class="contact"><label for="repassword">Confirm your password</label></p> 
        <input type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" required="" placeholder="Confirm password"> </br>

    <label>Birthday</label></br>
    <select class="select-style" name="birthMonth" >
     <option value="" class="nothing">Month</option>
     <option value="01">January</option>
     <option value="02">February</option>
     <option value="03" >March</option>
     <option value="04">April</option>
     <option value="05">May</option>
     <option value="06">June</option>
     <option value="07">July</option>
     <option value="08">August</option>
     <option value="09">September</option>
     <option value="10">October</option>
     <option value="11">November</option>
     <option value="12" >December</option>
    </select>

    <select class="select-style" name="birthDay" required="">
     <option value="" class="nothing">Day</option>
     <option value="01">01</option>
     <option value="02">02</option>
     <option value="03">03</option>
     <option value="04">04</option>
     <option value="05">05</option>
     <option value="06">06</option>
     <option value="07">07</option>
     <option value="08">08</option>
     <option value="09">09</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
     <option value="13">13</option>
     <option value="14">14</option>
     <option value="15">15</option>
     <option value="16">16</option>
     <option value="17">17</option>
     <option value="18">18</option>
     <option value="19">19</option>
     <option value="20">20</option>
     <option value="21">21</option>
     <option value="22">22</option>
     <option value="23">23</option>
     <option value="24">24</option>
     <option value="25">25</option>
     <option value="26">26</option>
     <option value="27">27</option>
     <option value="28">28</option>
     <option value="29">29</option>
     <option value="30">30</option>
     <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>  
    <input class="birthyear" maxlength="4" name="birthYear" placeholder="Year" required="" value="<?php echo $birthYear;?>">

    </br>
    <label>Gender</label>
    <select class="select-style" style="width:400px;" name="gender" >
      <option  class="nothing" value="select">i am..</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="others">Other</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Sign me up!*" type="submit"> 
    <font style="color:white; size:10px; background-color:black"> * - By clicking on "Sign me up" button, you completly agree with <a href="#terms-box" class="terms-window"><u>Terms & Conditions of use</u></a> .</font>
```

Validate:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //VARIABLES
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confPass = $_POST['repassword'];
    $birthDay = $_POST['birthDay'];
    $birthMonth = $_POST['birthMonth'];
    $birthYear = $_POST['birthYear'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $type = 'user';

    $birthday = date($birthDay."/".$birthMonth."/".$birthYear);


    $date0 = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
    $today = date("Y/m/d", $date0);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">','hideTerms();','</script>';




    if(strlen($password) < 5 or $password != $confPass){
        echo "<span id='abouTitle'> Something wrong..</span>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Password too small or different');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<span id='abouTitle'>Bem-Vindo, ".$username."!</span></br></br>";
        echo '<font style="color:white; font-size:20px;"';
        echo 'Name: '.$name.'</br>Email: '.$email.'</br>Username: '.$username.'</br>Password: <u>-Check your email-</u> </br>Birthday: '.$birthday.'</br>Gender: '.$gender.'</br>Account type: '.$type.'</br>Account Creation Day: '.$today.'</br>';


        include ('php/content/connect.php');
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password, /*birthday,*/ gender, accountType/*, creationDate*/) 
        VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$username', '$password',/*STR_TO_DATE('$birthYear,$birthMonth,$birthDay','%Y,%m,%d'),*/ '$gender', '$type'/*, '$today'*/") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_query($sql);
        $termina = mysql_close($conexao);

    }
}else{
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $birthYear ="";
    $username = "";
}echo '</font>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of parenthesis at the end of the syntax, you are closing the VALUES parenthesis but not the mysql_query one:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, password, /*birthday,*/ gender, accountType/*, creationDate*/) 
        VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$username', '$password',/*STR_TO_DATE('$birthYear,$birthMonth,$birthDay','%Y,%m,%d'),*/ '$gender', '$type'/*, '$today'*/ )")
```